# iText how to use PdfWriterPipeline and PdfSmartCopy at the same time?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I am using `iText` to convert HTML to PDF file. I realize the output file size is too huge so I decided to use `PdfSmartCopy` to remove the object duplication. I can use `PdfSmartCopy` after the HTML-to-PDF process finished, as in, I use `PdfSmartCopy` to load the file from disk and convert the PDF to smaller size.

My question is, can I streamline the `PdfSmartCopy` together with HTML-to-PDF process? I found that `PdfSmartCopy` is a subclass of `PdfWriter`. So I changed my code to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("output.pdf"))) {

        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

        //PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file); // remove this line 
        PdfSmartCopy pdfCopy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, file); // change to this line
        pdfCopy.setInitialLeading(12.5f);

        document.open();

        CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
        CssFile cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(new FileInputStream("itext2\\css\\bootstrap.min.css"));
        cssResolver.addCss(cssFile);

        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
        htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

        PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, pdfCopy);
        HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
        CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
        XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);

        String fileContent = PdfTest.readFile("itext2\\template.html");

        p.parse(new StringReader(fileContent));

        document.close();
        pdfCopy.close();
        file.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I got the error below:

```
ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPages.writePageTree(PdfPages.java:113)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.close(PdfWriter.java:1257)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy.close(PdfCopy.java:1698)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:895)
    at com.itextpdf.text.Document.close(Document.java:416)
    at pdftest.CompressPdfTest.main(CompressPdfTest.java:65)
```

Is it possible to use `PdfSmartCopy` at the same time of doing the HTML-to-PDF rendering?

https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/5.5.9/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfSmartCopy.html#PdfSmartCopy-com.itextpdf.text.Document-java.io.OutputStream-

Comment: No, it is not possible. You merely can keep the intermediate pdf file file in memory but as you consider its size too huge, you probably don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @mkl idea, during the HTML-to-PDF rendering, I saved it to memory, later on use `PdfSmartCopy` to generate slim pdf version, this can prevent me to generate two different pdf file in file system (later on have trouble to delete the non-slim one), paste the code below if it help others:

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteData = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {

    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, byteData);           
    writer.setInitialLeading(12.5f);

    document.open();

    CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
    CssFile cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(new FileInputStream("itext2\\css\\bootstrap.min.css"));
    cssResolver.addCss(cssFile);

    HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
    htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

    PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
    HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
    CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

    XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
    XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);

    String fileContent = PdfTest.readFile("itext2\\template.html");

    p.parse(new StringReader(fileContent));

    document.close();

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(byteData.toByteArray());
    Document document1 = new Document();
    File resultFile = new File("result.pdf");
    PdfSmartCopy pdfCopy = new PdfSmartCopy(document1, new FileOutputStream(resultFile));
    document1.open();
    PdfImportedPage page;
    for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); pageNumber++) {
        page = pdfCopy.getImportedPage(reader, pageNumber);
        pdfCopy.addPage(page);
    }

    document1.close();
    byteData.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```